# How to show php string in html input

Tags: php, string, http

I have a flat file TestFile.txt that has about 40 lines of data, each item on a separate row, so 40 lines. I have a PHP code that finds the row containing a string I want to find using using $Search_String. Then displays only the row containing $Search_String. This works exactly as I want. However; it displays the result in text area. How do I display the result into a label box?  The php reads the flat just as I would expect.  I have 2 html input fields, but the string $line only contains data inside the if statement.  Any help with this would be great!

Here is part of my flat file, filename is TestFile.txt:

```
RXFrequency=432675000
TXFrequency=432675000
RXOffset=260
TXOffset=120
Network=mnet.hopto.org
Password=8Yg81xrqK0313zt
Latitude=34.657783
Longitude=-3.784595
Port=62021
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$line = '';
?>

<input type="text" ID="message" value="<?php echo $line;?>"/>

<?php

// Place text to look for in string $Search_String.
// The $Search_String will remain hard coded in my production
// code. The users will not be able to select $Search_String.
$Search_String = "RXF";
// Identify Text File, open File and Read the File.
$MyFile = fopen("TestFile.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$found= "False";
// Create the while loop.  Test each line with the if statement,
// looking for $Search_String, and place the result into string $line.
// Next, echo string $line which containes the found line in the 
// flat text file.  It will return the entire line even from a 
// partial $Search_String, which is what I want.
while ( $line = fgets( $MyFile ) )
  {
    if ( str_contains( $line, $Search_String ) ) 
     {
     echo $line;
     echo $Search_String;
     }
  } 

// Properly close the text file.
   fclose($MyFile);
?>

<input type="text" id="message" value="<?php echo $line;?>"/>

</body>
</html>
```

This code does properly open the flat text file, it does the search and finds
the line containing the data I am trying to retrieve.  I see the correct gata using echo in the if statement.  Now I need to place the found data into the html input text box.  The string $line seems to contain no data outside the if block of code.  Can I make the variable $line static or global so the data is available throughout the code?  Or am I using the html input text improperly?  I think I do need to use input text, because I want to be able to modify the data and then write the line back to the flat file.

Thanks for any suggestions,
Mitch

Comment: you should declare a var outside the while block scope as an array and inside the if condition, push the line into the array. So out of the while loop you'll have an array with all the lines matching the criteria. Then you should loop the items in the array and echo the html with that value. The approach you are using for the input text doesn't take into account the possibility that the $line content contains double quotes non escaped

Comment: Sounds like this could work. Can you show sample code, as I have only been doing php a little over a week!  Trying to learn fast, though.  Only one line will match the search criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a small grasp of your code including the proposed solution to loop through and show all the lines matching the criteria from your file:

```
<?php

/*...*/

$lines = [];

while ( $line = fgets( $MyFile ) ) {
    if ( str_contains( $line, $Search_String ) ) {
        //here you are keeping track of each line matching criteria
        $lines[] = $line;
        
        //echo $line;
        //echo $Search_String;
    }
} 
?>

<?php foreach($lines as $line): ?>
    <input type="text" value="<?= $line; ?>"/> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Diego, that works really smooth.  The input box populates perfectly!!!  I have been working on that 3 days, you fixed it in 9 minutes!  Thanks a lot........

Comment: feel free to accept the answer then! :) I'm glad it worked